# Programming Maze Solution recursively

Tags: python

This function is intended to recursively navigate a maze and find the length of the shortest path. The path itself is not necessary, only the length. The maze is represented by a 2d list with values such as

```
0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

The user starts at (0,0) and must end up at the end of the maze as defined (in my case it is the bottom right cell). 1's represent walls.

```
def maze(x,y,array,length):
    m = len(array)
    n = len(array[0])
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x == m or y == n or array[x][y] == 1:
        return float("inf")
    elif x == m - 1 and y == n - 1:
        return length
    else:
        array[x][y] = 1
        up = maze(x - 1,y,array,length + 1)
        right = maze(x,y + 1,array,length + 1)
        down = maze(x + 1,y,array,length + 1)
        left = maze(x,y - 1,array,length + 1)
        return min(up,down,left,right)


array = [[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]
minLength = maze(0,0,array,1)
print(minLength)
```

I designed it so that it recursively finds all possible paths from each direction (up, down, left and right), and returns the lowest value from all these paths with each step of the way. It returns inf for any path that is not valid.

For this specific array, it returns 11, which is false, it should be 9. I do not believe it is merely a mathematical error, as I tried printing each step of the way and it is not recognizing certain paths (it returns inf for paths that most definitely have options).

I can't seem to find where my code is going wrong, it seems like it should properly return the value, but in practice it does not.

Comment: When you recursively call `maze()` to calculate `up`, you possibly turn one of the cells into a 1.  That cell is then not available when calculating the other three directions...  Same thing for `right` and `down`, with the two or one following directions.

Comment: This is a *backtracking* example, in *2D* (that I've studied in hi-school - such a  problem was the very example). Note that *backtracking* finds **all** the possibilities (you can get your best from there), but it's  like kind of *brute force*.

Comment: When I run your code, it returns 9. (I'm using Python 3)

Comment: Exactly as @jasonharper says. Your solution first goes the long way (down down, right right, up up, right right, down down) then it’s unable to take any other route, including the shortest one.

Comment: Why does it turn the array into 1's for the rest of the other paths? When it goes up and turns the array into 1's, is that not exclusive to that specific path? Wouldn't right, down and left utilize the original array given up to that point? Is Python somehow storing the array outside of the scope of the function?

Answer (score 1):

`array` is a *reference* to the original array, not a local copy.  See any of the on-line tutorials on how Python passes function arguments, or how it handles lists.  You can see the effect by printing `array` in your main program after the call to `maze`:

```
Final Maze [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]
```

Fixing this is relatively easy: copy the nested list and use that copy locally.

```
from copy import deepcopy

def maze(x,y,array,length):
    m = len(array)
    n = len(array[0])
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x == m or y == n or array[x][y] == 1:
        return float("inf")
    elif x == m - 1 and y == n - 1:
        return length
    else:
        new_maze = deepcopy(array)
        new_maze[x][y] = 1
        up = maze(x - 1,y,new_maze,length + 1)
        right = maze(x,y + 1,new_maze,length + 1)
        down = maze(x + 1,y,new_maze,length + 1)
        left = maze(x,y - 1,new_maze,length + 1)
        return min(up,down,left,right)


array = [[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]
minLength = maze(0,0,array,1)
print("Final Maze", array)
print(minLength)
```

The output from this is (edited for readability again)

```
Final Maze [
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
]
9
```

Comment: You could also just restore the original maze state with `array[x][y] = 0` just before returning, which would on a somewhat larger example would safe quite a bit of time

Comment: @happydave: Correct.  I've been doing too much parallel programming lately.